# how to get next key in json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, angular

Trying to compare next json key with the current.

my json object is as  below

table_0: {
TR4TD1: 'Region\n\n',
TR4TD2: 'Actual Generation (MU) during May \n',
TR4TD5: 'Actual Generation (MU) during\nApril to May\n\n',
TR5TD2: '2019\n',
TR5TD3: '2018\n',
TR5TD4: '% Growth\n',
TR5TD5: '2019\n',
TR5TD6: '2018\n',
TR5TD7: '% Growth'
}

I am trying using the

Object.entries(obj).forEach(key, value)=>{

// here i want to access current key and next key

//for e.g. current key 'TR4TD2', next key 'TR4TD5'

})